# Node.js and SQL: How can I get the value outside of the for loop?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, promise

Using Node.js and a MySQL database I'm working on a small project.

I'm trying to loop through an array to get some values out of a MySQL database. I'm searching for the corresponding "medicine ID" to an "medicine name" that the user entered. My Code is working correctly and this is how it looks.

```js
var medizinArray = [];

function appendArray(input) {
  medizinArray.push(input);
}

var sqlMedNameToId = "SELECT MedikamentId FROM Medikament WHERE Bezeichnung = ?"

for (var i=0;i<medicineMontag.length;i++){
  var montagsMedizin = medicineMontag[i];
  mySqlConnection.query(sqlMedNameToId, montagsMedizin, function(err, rows, fields){
    if(!err) {
      result = rows[0].MedikamentId;
      appendArray(result);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      }
  })
}

console.log(medizinArray);
```

The code is working but I can't get the **medizinArray** out of the for loop. In my console I get an empty array. When I put the **console.log(medizinArray)** inside the for loop I get the array that I want.

I'm currently not familiar with Promises. I read about it and saw some other questions but I can't figure out how to implement Promises in my code.

Comment: 'I'm currently not familiar with Promises'. Asyncronous programming(`async/await`,`Promise`) is a big part of javascript programming. You should learn at least the basics first. Otherwise there is no point in answering your question anyways

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV thanks for the advice. I guess I can't say anything against that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL operations are asynchronous, so to obtain the result outside of the callback you need to wrap them in a Promise and call the resolve() function when the operation is successful.  Use any of the techniques below:

*Async/await technique:*

```
(async function(){
  let medizinArray = [];

function appendArray(input) {
  medizinArray.push(input);
}

let sqlMedNameToId = "SELECT MedikamentId FROM Medikament WHERE Bezeichnung = ?"
await new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
let e;
for (let i=0;i<medicineMontag.length;i++){
  let montagsMedizin = medicineMontag[i];
  mySqlConnection.query(sqlMedNameToId, montagsMedizin, function(err, rows, fields){
    if(e) return; 
    if(!err) {
      result = rows[0].MedikamentId;
      appendArray(result);
    } else {
      //console.log(err);
      e = true; 
      return reject(err);
      }
    if(i == medicineMontag.length-1) resolve(result);
  })
}
}
);

console.log(medizinArray);//now medizinArray shows up here
})().catch(function(err){console.log(err)});
```

*Promise/then technique:*

```
let medizinArray = [];

function appendArray(input) {
  medizinArray.push(input);
}

let sqlMedNameToId = "SELECT MedikamentId FROM Medikament WHERE Bezeichnung = ?"

new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
let e; 
for (let i=0;i<medicineMontag.length;i++){
  let  montagsMedizin = medicineMontag[i];
  mySqlConnection.query(sqlMedNameToId, montagsMedizin, function(err, rows, fields){
    if(e) return;
    if(!err) {
      result = rows[0].MedikamentId;
      appendArray(result);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      e = true; 
      return reject(err); 
      }
    if(i == medicineMontag.length-1) resolve(result);
  })
}
}
).then(function(result){
console.log(medizinArray);//now medizinArray shows up here
}).catch(function(err){
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I trief both of your solutions but I can't get it run in my program. In my console I don't get an error so I don't see where the problem could be.

I'm still trying to get my head around the concept of syncronous/asyncronous concepts of javascript. If I can bring my code to work I will post my answer.

Comment: @durikr I have updated my answer. The problem was the use of var keyword excessively in your code. As a caveat, don't use var keyword in for loops. I have changed all var keywords to let keywords though.